# Is there a way to make GNOME Panel backgrounds stretch vertically, rather than repeat?

Tags: gnome, theme, gnome-panel

I have another strange issue with the GNOME Panel. Images (that I am using as backgrounds) instead of scaling vertically, are actually repeating vertically, leaving me with a really weird effect:

[image: Horizontal Line example 1]

[image: Horizontal Line example 2]

Notice the **horizontal** line straight through the middle of the panel, this is the edge at which the pattern repeats. I'm using SVG images for the background, so scaling shouldn't be an issue.

Is there a way to specify "scale" and not "repeat" for vertical layout? This whole thing is brought on by having a panel size not in keeping with the defaults, and I need the extra panel size because of the icon set I'm using.

Comment: Why not scale the background image itself?

Comment: its not possible to stretch image itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this issue under Debian Squeeze versions 6.0.2 and 6.0.3, which I chose because they [were released on 25 June and 8 October in 2011](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianSqueeze?highlight=%28CategoryRelease%29) respectively. Judging by other questions of the same author from that time, it could be Debian. GNOME version is 2.30.2.

After some trials and exploring with `gconftool-2`, I found that the settings to stretch the background images of the panels were disabled by default under Debian. To enable vertical stretching for the bottom panel:

```
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/panel/toplevels/bottom_panel_screen0/background/stretch true
```

This works for background images chosen manually. I checked SVG and PNG.